# Trying to map inside of map in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map inside of a map function but I'm getting an error saying that data.map is not a function.

Here is the code:

```
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style={{ fontSize: 10, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {
                                            props.data.body.table.tableData.map((data, idx) => (
                                                <tr key={idx}>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {
                                                            data.map((newdata, idx2) => (
                                                                {newdata}
                                                            ))
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            ))
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

What's the issue here?

I also get a syntax error if I bind my newData with Object.values like this:   {Object.values(newData)}

If I console.log 'data', I get this: Essentially, I just want values instead of keys.

[image]

Comment: That probably means that your `data` variable is not an array.

Comment: On mapping like this, I again get an error. Basically, I'm trying to convert the variable into array:   Object.values(data).map((newdata, idx2) => (
                                                                    {newdata}
                                                                ))

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the screen but on console I'm getting this error: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {newdata}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: try to remove curly braces around `newdata`

Comment: Doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: create a codesandbox regenerating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to achieve something like this

```
 <tr key={idx}>
   {Object.values(data).map((newdata, idx2) => (<td key={idx2}>{newdata}</td>))}
 </tr>
```

Also, you should avoid like this `props.data.body.table`. You need to use destructuring, e.g.

```
const { data: { body } } = props
```

and so on.

I also would consider checking whether data is actually available to use. What I mean by that is any on an object in between `props.data.body.table` can be `null` or `undefined` which leads to runtime error.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but getting the same error. Data.map is not a function. Check my edited question.

Comment: Hi, check my answer where I modified your code slightly. If you edit your answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ShridharK is that what you meant?  Keep in mind that you need to avoid things like `props.data.body.table` it looks like a code smell and it really can produce runtime exceptions

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're trying to call an array method '.map' on non-array value.

To solve this, check that all values are arrays inside `data`.

If it is intended that some values can be not arrays, you can use optional chaining.

```
data?.map((newdata, idx2) => (
  {newdata}
))
```

It will check if data exists, and if it doesn't, React will render nothing.

If it wasn't intended to have objects, use `Object.values(data).map(...rest of the code)`

Comment: Adding question mark doesn't work and throws the same error. By the way, I have added a screenshot of the data to my question

Comment: Then, how to convert to array and map on it? I want to convert it to array inside of the map itself.

Comment: @ShridharK do you mean that you call `.map` method on the stuff in curly braces? Or you have shown the data from `newData`?

Comment: I want to map on 'data' and then I want to show the values inside td. Check the screenshot of the data object.

Comment: You can do so using Object.values(data).map(...the rest of the code)

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that but nothing gets displayed on the screen, instead I get an error on the console called: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {newdata}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of head-scratching, got the answer. I built up the solution of @SuperManEver and just made a slight modification to his code where I added Object.values to it. And surprisingly it worked!

```
   <tr key={idx}>
      {Object.values(data).map((newdata, idx2) => (<td key={idx2}>{newdata}</td>))}
   </tr>
```

The objective of this code was me trying to dynamically add rows and columns to a table simply based on the data passed.